# RelativeLayout contents are going beyond the screen size

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

in the code i have given height and width for image in dp only. but still entire contents of the screen going off the screen in lower screen sizes. I have tested in emulator and real device its looking decent in 5.5 inch screen and not looking good in other screen sizes.

Please find code below.
Mail Xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="reminder.locrem.com.locationreminder.AddLocationReminder">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_add_location_reminder" />



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Content xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_add_location_reminder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="reminder.locrem.com.locationreminder.AddLocationReminder"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_add_location_reminder">


    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:id="@+id/addImage"
        android:background="@android:drawable/screen_background_light_transparent"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:onClick="launchChooseImageDialog"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/setImage"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/addImage" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Add Items"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/addItemsLaunchTextBox"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.AutoCompleteTextView"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:hint="Add Items"
        android:onClick="launchAddItemsActivity"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:focusable="false"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="Select Place"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/addItemsLaunchTextBox"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/selectPlaceEditText"
        android:hint="Choose Place"
        android:onClick="launchChooseLocationActivity"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:focusable="false"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="Choose Image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/selectPlaceEditText"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/setImage"
        android:id="@+id/add_reminder"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@color/cast_libraries_material_featurehighlight_outer_highlight_default_color"
        android:text="Add"
        android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:elevation="11dp"
        android:onClick="saveLocationReminder"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Please find screenshots for reference

4 inch screen
[image: 4 inch screen]

4.7 inch screen
[image: 4.7 inch screen]

5.5 inch screen
[image: 5.5 inch screen]

Answer (score 0):

check this library i'm using it and solved my problem ,hope to solve yours
https://github.com/intuit/sdp

Answer (score 0):

Do you provide drawable for all dimensions? Check your `res` folder and make sure you have drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi and so on.

On different screen sizes and resolutions system will use different resources and in your situation looks like you provide only one image.

Please, refer to this guide [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)